# How to open a message/mime digest (within Gnus?), like ~/mail/Incoming<code>

Tags: gnus, email, message

Recently I did some shit within Gnus: I deleted a lot (thousands) of mails, trying to respool them in another group and rename it to the first group after having deleted it (i.e. to prepend an old mailing-list group to the new one that changed name)… but well I got a backup but quite old… and since it’s mailing-lists I hope to get back some mails asking to other people subscribed to send them to me…

Waiting for that, what interest me now are recent mails: and I just noticed that I still have a *lot* of `Incoming<code>` within my `~/mail`, and I think that could make a backup: do someone know how to “re-receive them”? aka exctract from these digests the mails of theses groups and respool them into them? I tried to open groups like `nnmbox:Incoming<code>` but it doesn’t work (“No such group”).

So how to open/respool that? It should be easy it’s just a digest of a lot of MIME messages…

PS: I also tried to see what does functions like `nnmail-split-incoming` but couldn’t figure out how to use it.

Comment: I succeded that 1 times on 3. The two others I thing I did something wrong by disattention. But I know how to do it ;) The question would be more: how to extract only the mails of these groups ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IncomingXXXXX-files are backups of incoming email (typically only enabled in development versions of Gnus). The variable `mail-source-delete-incoming` controls the behaviour.

You can open an mbox file using the command `G f` (gnus-group-make-doc-group) which prompts you for a file name. You can then copy the emails from the new group corresponding to the file to whatever group you want them in.

(Another way is to copy the IncomingXXXXX-files into /var/mail/YOURLOGIN, if you have configured Gnus to fetch email from there, but with `G f` you have more control over the process.)

Comment: Great (yeah I knew for `mail-source-delete-incoming` ;))! that advance me a lot (last time I read the Gnus manual was long time ago and I wasn’t going to read it entirely again to remember ^^") \o/ Now a little question: do you know if there’s a way to “extract” all mails of some defined groups from these files or should I ask another separate question elsewhere?

Comment: Ok I had to temporary modify `nnmail-split-fancy`

Comment: @galex-713 Sorry, I don't understand your question. Is respooling what you are thinking of (`B r`)?